# Ionic Nav View and AngularUI rendering template twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I'm using this ionic template https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu to start with a header/left-menu kind  of app, everything is looking good, however the views are being rendered twice, exactly on top of each others, please check the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ywqviKDnQE for the effect, I double checked that the controller is not executed twice, have no idea why im getting this effect.

I'm using Chrome, and also noticed that whenver i changed the tab, and go back to this chrome tab again, the issue disappesrs, so it definitely has something to do with repaint/redrawing.

Comment: Without code, its pretty hard to know what is going on here exactly. However, do you have any custom CSS on that view? Can you share some of the code you've written?

Comment: Please create a plunkr showing the problem.

Comment: guys, it was a css problem, a lot of floating left divs, completely unrelated to angular or ionic, sorry for wasting ur time

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you create a new application with ionic -in your case sidemenu-, it has its default CSS, components and AngularJS Extensions.

Based on the video you provided, I can't figure out what's the exact issue without seeing the code, but I preffer you check those links about app scrolling because I think it's probably a problem with the scrolling.

[AngularJS: API: $anchorScrollProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$anchorScrollProvider)

[ion-scroll - $ionicScrollDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)